# Google Analytics - Tracking divs inside a container

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, event-tracking

I want to know if there is a way to track both clicks and Views from some ads (just a image with a link) that will apear randomly inside a container div. And if I can get these values by the id of the ads on my Google Analytics page.

```
<center><div id="MP_AD_CONTAINER">
        <a href="http://www.superbock.pt" target="_blank"><div id="super_bock_ad" class="ad"></div></a>
        <div id="EDP_ad" class="ad"></div>
        <div id="Sisab_ad" class="ad"></div>
    </div></center>



        <script>

        //Array with Id of divs to show:
        var Ids = ["super_bock_ad", "EDP_ad", "Sisab_ad"];

        //Chose a Id randomly:
        var chosenValue = Ids[Math.floor(arrayDeIds.length * Math.random())];
        var chosenDiv = document.getElementById(chosenValue);

        //Shows the chosenDiv inside container: 
        chosenDiv.style.display = "block";

        // Counter to call a function giveTheViews() only once:
        var count = 0;

        document.getElementById('MP_AD_CONTAINER').addEventListener("click", function(){

           //Google analytics code to track clicks From chosenDiv (?)
           _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Interactions', 'Click', chosenValue]);

        });

        window.onscroll = function(ev) {
           //Test to know if the div was seen:
           if (window.innerHeight >= (document.getElementById("MP_AD_CONTAINER").getBoundingClientRect().top +(document.getElementById("MP_AD_CONTAINER").offsetHeight / 2) )) {

                if(count == 0){
                    getTheViews();
                    count = 1;
                }
            }
        };

        function getTheViews(){
            //Hey Google Analytics! Save the number of people that view this ad!
             _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Images', 'View', chosenValue]);
        }
```

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Can you please share what things you have tried to get this tracking working (ie. your code or other efforts)?

Comment: Thanks, so what have you tried so far to do the tracking? And to confirm you are using classic GA, right? Also, can you narrow down the code to the relevant pieces (like I don't need to see the CSS, etc.)?

Comment: Hey Nyuen! Yes. I am using the regular, classic, normal Google Analytics.

I want to know if after make the functions is it necessary to change something in the Google Analytics painel? 
Plus: 
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Interactions', 'Click', chosenValue]); -> Count the number of clicks.
What "action", "opt_label" count the number of views? 

Thank you.

Comment: You don't have to configure anything to see events (if that's what you're asking). Also, the event action and label are totally up to you. I advise that you should install GA Debugger for Chrome so that you can see the events firing. That way you'll know if your code is working as expected or not, and you can tweak as necessary.